# how to make a blacklist-based filter in react input component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to make a filter for react input component? Just like

```
Class InputFilter extends Component {
  state = { text: ''}
  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({text: e.target.value})
  }
  handleSubmit = () => {
    this.state.text.filter(...) // filter '<' '>' '/' and any other specific characters
    ... // pass this text to another component
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <input type='text' value="this.state.text" onChange={this.handleChange}>
      <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}/>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: your handleSubmit function is handling the entire form and not the input. Might want to work on that, but I have given an answer below on how to filter the input value, without fixing your entire workflow.

Comment: Sorry for this mistake, I have updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

if you really want to use filter, 
you can split all characters in the string into an array, then filter, then join.

```
val.split("").filter(character => !character.match(/* place in regular expression */) ).join("")
```

Comment: I think it is better to change the title to a scope of js level, always thank for this respond.

Comment: What do you mean change the title to a scope of js level? This is js.